# Getting flyway to ignore indices

Tags: flyway

Often times DBAs like to add, remove, or tune indices as this sort of work is in their wheel-house. Is there a way to have Flyway ignore indices so these can be added ad-hoc by DBAs? I would like flyway to manage the database structure, tables, constraints, etc. but still allow DBAs to add indices for reports and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are free to manage the subset of objects you want using Flyway. You can do tables, your DBAs can do indices.

The only thing you need to be careful about is using clean(), as this will wipe your complete schema (including indices).